# Estimate for $n$th prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A good approximation I have found for $p_{n}$ is

\begin{align}
\int_{2}^{n}\log (x \log (x \log (x)))\ dx\\
\end{align}

and seems to be a better estimate than $n \log (n)$.

The error term seems to agree with the asymptotic expansion of Cipolla:

$$p_n=n\log n+n\log\log n-n+n\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}+O(n(\log\log n/\log n)^2)$$

(from [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98566/asymptotics-of-the-n-th-prime-using-the-gamma-function)) where the $O$ term is replaced for a constant (in this case, $-e$).

Perhaps more interestingly, it seems that applying successive $\log$ terms to the integral

\begin{align}
&\int_{2}^{n}\log (x)\ dx&\tag{1}\\
&\int_{2}^{n}\log (x \log (x))\ dx &\tag{2}\\
&\int_{2}^{n}\log (x \log (x \log (x)))\ dx &\tag{3}\\
&\int_{2}^{n}\log (x \log (x \dots \log (x)))\ dx &\tag{4}\\
\end{align}

seems to move very slowly towards a better asymptotic. Is this the case?

## Added

Numerical results at @RghtHndSd's request:

Firstly comparing $\color{blue}{n \log (n)},\ \color{green}{\int_{2}^{n}\log (x \log (x \log (x)))\ dx}$ and $\color{red}{p_{n}}$ at successive powers of $10$

[image]

with

```
p[x_] := Round@(x Log[x])
p3[x_] := Round@NIntegrate[Log[n Log[n Log[n]]], {n, 2, x}]
Grid[tab2 = Table[{Style[p[n], FontColor -> Blue],
Style[p3[n], FontColor -> Darker@Green],
Style[Prime[n], FontColor -> Red]}, {n, Table[10^j, {j, 1, 12}]}],
ItemSize -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

and then comparing successive $\log$ terms

[image]

with

```
p1[x_] := Round@NIntegrate[Log[n], {n, 2, x}]
p2[x_] := Round@NIntegrate[Log[n Log[n]], {n, 2, x}]
p3[x_] := Round@NIntegrate[Log[n Log[n Log[n]]], {n, 2, x}]
p4[x_] := Round@Re@NIntegrate[Log[n Log[n Log[n Log[n]]]], {n, 2, x}]
p5[x_] := Round@Re@NIntegrate[Log[n Log[n Log[n Log[n Log[n]]]]], {n, 2, x}]
Grid[tab2 = Table[{p1[n], p2[n], p3[n], p4[n], p5[n]}, 
{n, Table[10^j, {j, 1, 12}]}], ItemSize -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

which, although `p5[n]` exceeds $p_{n}$ at $10^{12}$, the successive log terms added to the integral clearly approach a limit near to the asymptote of $p_{n}$. This is not as good, I think, as $\operatorname{li}^{-1}(n)$, but this is difficult to compute for large $n$.

## Improved results

It may be that

\begin{align}
&\int_{2}^{n}\log (x \log (x \log (x)/e))\ dx\\
\end{align}

is better.

[image]

\begin{align}
&&
\text{left hand column}&\quad\left|1-n \dfrac{\log(n)}{p_{n}}\right|&\\
\\
&&
\text{middle column}&\quad\left|1-\dfrac{\int_{2}^{n}\log (x \log (x \log (x)))\ dx}{p_{n}}\right|&\\
\\
&&
\text{right hand column}&\quad\left|1-\dfrac{\int_{2}^{n}\log (x \log (x \log (x)/e))\ dx+\frac{9}{2}\sqrt{n}}{p_{n}}\right|&\\
\end{align}

running from $10^{1}$ to $10^{12}$.

## Minor improvements

As daniel says, it is likely there are a lot of trailing terms. The best I have been able to manage so far is

\begin{align}
&\int_{2}^{n}\log (x \log (x \log (x)/e))\ dx+4 \sqrt{x}+\frac{x}{23 \log ^2(x)}+\frac{x}{23 \log (x)}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{23 \log (x)}\\
\end{align}

but it is only really accurate up to $10^{11}$

[image]

[image]

which can be seen to tail off just after $10^{11}$.

```
pbs[x_] :=  Re@NIntegrate[Log[n Log[n Log[E^E, n]]], {n, 2, x}] 
+ 4 Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[x]/(23 Log[x]) + x/(23 Log[x]) + x/(23 Log[x]^2)

GraphicsGrid[{
Table[ListLinePlot[Transpose@Table[{(pbs[n] - Prime[n])
/(30 Sqrt[n]/Log[n])}, {n, 2, 10^k, 10^(k - 1)/2}]], {k, 2, 4}],
Table[ListLinePlot[Transpose@Table[{(pbs[n] - Prime[n])
/(30 Sqrt[n]/Log[n])}, {n, 2, 10^k, 10^(k - 1)/2}]], {k, 5, 7}],    
Table[ListLinePlot[Transpose@Table[{(pbs[n] - Prime[n])
/(30 Sqrt[n]/Log[n])}, {n, 2, 10^k, 10^(k - 1)/2}]], {k, 8, 10}],    
Table[ListLinePlot[Transpose@Table[{(pbs[n] - Prime[n])
/(30 Sqrt[n]/Log[n])}, {n, 2, 10^k, 10^(k - 1)/2}]], {k, 11, 12}]}, ImageSize -> 1000]]
```

Comment: This is way beyond my understanding but it looks pretty. Could you make graphs of $\frac{p_n}{\int_2^n\left(\log\left(x\log\left(x\cdots\left(\log x\right)\cdots\right)\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x}$ maybe?

Comment: Number (2) in your list is I think just the PNT in disguise...so I guess this will fall out as a consequence of the PNT.

Comment: @daniel I am pretty sure they all fall out of the PNT. The point is, how good are the estimates? (There are at least two form of the PNT: (a) that $\pi(n)\sim\ n/\log(n)$, and (b) $\pi(n)\sim\ \operatorname{li}(n)$)

Comment: @daniel - yes, just looking at includiong prime powers now ...

Comment: @martin: If you are going to post more numerical data, post the difference a_n - p_n and p_n in two columns, rather than a_n and p_n in two columns. Of course, one could also use a_n/p_n instead of the difference.

Comment: For plotting numbers, it might be more useful to plot the ratio of an estimate with the true value; e.g. rather than both $n \log n$ and $p_n$, you tabulate $$ \frac{n \log n}{p_n}$$

Comment: I see no reason to think that each additional log in your integrals improves the accuracy of the estimate - unless the estimates are all underestimates, say, and slightly increasing the function gets closer just for size reasons (without approaching the true size), having nothing to do with the suitability of the complicated integrals to the task.

Comment: Iterating the logs indefinitely, I believe, gives $$ \log(x \log(x \ldots)) = -W_{-1}(-1/x)$$ where $W_{-1}$ is one of the branches of the Lambert W function.

Comment: @Hurkyl how do you get $\log(x \log(x \ldots)) = -W_{-1}(-1/x)?$

Comment: @martin: Wolframalpha. Alternatively, if $y$ is the iterated log, then $y = \log(xy)$ and $-1/x = -y e^{-y}$

Comment: @Hurkyl just out of curiosity, what did you input to WolframAlpha to get that?

Comment: @Hurkyl can't seem to replicate that in WA ...

Comment: @martin: WA does give the answer, just in a different form: see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-W%28-1%2C+-1%2Fx%29%29%2Fx+%3D%3D+-W%28-1%2C+-1%2Fx%29

Comment: @Hurkyl when written like that it seems obvious! Thank you for that - it is much clearer now :)

Comment: I suppose I should point out that I found WA much less satisfactory than usual in this derivation.

Answer (score 2):

adding more log terms will only increase the value of the integral.as it is the value of your integral exceeds the value of the nth prime. what is more the error seems to be getting greater as pn gets larger. I strongly suspect that further numerical results will be in favour of PNT, even an asymptotic relation I think, will not hold. However under certain lower and upper bounds the estimate may be better than PNT.